# FIREMONKEY android how to switch activity from the same projet

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

My enterprise uses delphi and firemonkey to develop android applications,
I want a basic application with 2 screens, and with the possibility to go from screen A to screen B . In java it's easy by making an intent but I Don't know how to do it with Firemonkey and Delphi.
I have one project "project1" with 2 units . Let's say "UnitA" and "UnitB", so the package will be "com.embarcadero.project1", and the className is "com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity" by default, but is there one className for everyUnit?
Which className shall I pass to the Intent to get to the unitB?
(FMXNativeActivity is set by default on the AndroidManifest.xml automatically created)

Comment: There's a sample of using multiple forms in the samples included with the product. In 10.1 Berlin, it's in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\Forms

Comment: FMXNativeActivity is the base to show the app by the FMX framework. All the rest forms in the project are drawn by the framework and they are not activities (FMX app uses NDK and OpenGL to draw complete user interface, for Android there are no native controls). You should follow the example mentioned above, and to simply choose the starting form you can set it in the IDE (Project/Options/Forms/Main form).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand everything you wrote, but if you just have 2 .pas in a project, and from the first one you want to show the second one, I know 2 ways to switch :

First way : you can open a modal window

```
if not Assigned(FormUnitB) then
    FormUnitB:= TFormUnitB.Create(self);

FormUnitB.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
        if ModalResult = mrOK then
            //nothing here, when you want to close you write it in the modal
    end);
```

Second way : you use layouts : in UnitA, you put an empty layout (LayoutA for example). In UnitB, you put another layout (LayoutB), that will contains all the components of the UnitB, and when you want to show the UnitB, you put the LayoutB in the LayoutA

```
LayoutA.AddObject(FormUnitB.LayoutB);
```

Note : to do this you need to specify that UnitA uses UnitB.